# Disabling user interaction in entire screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

I have a main controller and adding picker view when user selects SORT. I want to disable complete user interaction except Picker Control (Cancel and Done Button). I am adding picker as subview to window.

I tried using following before and after animation but it disables everything including Picker Controls.

```
UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

**Is there any other solution to disable user interaction app wide?**

[image]

Comment: You are supposed to modal present a full screen Vc with a transparent main view and then add pickle view. This way you have much more controls over user interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the picker is added to window's view , you can do this in the currentVC

```
self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled =  // true/false
```

also as you have a navigation , you may also do

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled =  // true/false
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt applies to `UIApplication.shared`, which is the entire application. You can try just disabling one window, or one view, or a series of views, by setting the `isUserInteractionEnabled` property on the view or views you want to disable.

Please note, though, that what you are attempting is atypical design. A user should generally be able to tap on whatever is onscreen. For example, if the user taps the back button in the upper left, the keyboard should dismiss and the previous view should appear.

If for some reason this selection really *needs* to be modal, it might be simpler to just present a modal view controller over this one.